# Matrix indexing in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:
ex:

```
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3   4
[2,]    5    6    7   8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
```

When i access eighth element it gives me 7 like

```
> x[8]
  7
```

I want to access 8 when i type x[8] like

```
 > x[8]
   8
```

The fact is R indexes a matrix elements in top left to bottom left format but i want to  index it in top left to to top right format.

How is this possible? Are there any additional arguments to use to do so?

Comment: Try `x[2, 4]`, second row, fourth column.

Comment: Or `t(x)[8]` if you must

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
t(x)[index]
```

You input is

```
> x = t(matrix(1:12, 4))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
```

You can get

```
> t(x)[1]
[1] 1
> t(x)[8]
[1] 8
> t(x)[12]
[1] 12
```